# Swift 4 in Xcode 9 - How to do some animation during dragging UItextview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I have make a animation in the view above UItextview, and it looks like very smooth. I used a timer to do this animation.

But there is a problem about when I drag the textview, the animation can be paused if it haven't ended. So, is there a way to permit a animation play smoothly with the textview scrolling or being dragged.

---

OK, I speak as clear as possible.
I'm poor in English, excuse me.

A UItextview, which can be scrolled. And a button on the other view (this view which is not associated with that UItextview). That two views are in a big view at the same time. the button become big when you touch it, this process is concerned about an animation.But when the textview scrolling, this animation can be paused if it start and haven't end.

A function called when button have touched, this animation is a timer, and it's location in a array in each frame.

And how to pause animation in detail:

Use a finger touch this button, and its animation can be triggered. And before this animation ended, use another finger drag the textview, I can find obviously this animation is paused ,and it continued when I lift up my finger in the textview.

So, why all animations were paused when a textview (or a scroll view) scrolled. is this a system program? How to solve this problem?

If you have any other doubts, please put questions in the comment field.

this animation like this:

```
var TimerCount = 0
var timer = timer()
timer = timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.02, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
    /*Some animation code*/
    if TimerCount >= 19 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    TimerCount += 1
})
```

Comment: Please share your code for what you have tried and possibly some screenshots as this question appears unclear

Comment: While I do have already an idea of which the problem might be, please give us some code to help you better. How do you actually animate this UITextView?

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza I have updated my question, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the "pausing" issue is resolvable within your code, I must say for the records that this is not the right way to perform an animation.

I suggest you to take a look at CABasicAnimation and the CoreAnimation framework way to perform correctly animation taking advantage of the GPU.

As always Ray Wenderlich makes amazing [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113686/ios-animation-tutorial-introduction-easy-animation) about this subject.

So said, the pausing occurs because the timer is scheduled using the schedule method. you must add your timer to the main runloop to avoid that this gets interrupted by user actions. Again, this is not the proper way to animate something on screen on iOS and most likely you will have performances issues.

```
var timerCount = 0
let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.02, repeats: true) { (timer) in
  /*Some animation code*/
  if TimerCount >= 19 {
    timer.invalidate()
  }
  timerCount += 1
}
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
```

While this code gives you a solution, I strongly recommend to not perform animations this way. It works, eventually you will have exactly what you want, but in the future you will probably have problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use timer to perform animation because CABasicAnimation is limited. It just used for location, frame, scale, color, etc. But it can not change such as, font size, kern, etc. in animation. So I think timer has no limitation, which is the best way to custom animations. So do you have any idea for custom animations? Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, with some code you can animate pretty much anything. If you don't want to write extra code there are animatable properties you can use for your purposes. for the case of font size you might animate the label's transform for example. a lot varies on the result you want to achieve, but this would be another question. Better not to go off topic here.

Comment: But the font size, even attributed text has no animation properties, but timer is the most way to custom these animations. No matter what animation I want to perform, it always performs more previously,and more beautifully. Because I can control the value every frame previously. That's all, thank you very much!